# NameError: name 'contSearch' is not defined

Tags: python

So i was experimenting with a mini search engine system in which you can choose to view 2 separate pages (printed into the console). I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/normytemporary/Desktop/InfoApp.py", line 21, in <module>
    y = page(input)
  File "/Users/normytemporary/Desktop/InfoApp.py", line 19, in page
    y = contSearch(input)
NameError: name 'contSearch' is not defined
```

The error is related to this function:

```
def contSearch(x):
    x = input('Would you like to visit another page?')
    while x == 'yes':
        y = page(input)
    while x == 'no':
        print ('Search terminated. Please restart to search again')
        y = 0
    while x != 'yes' or 'no':
        print ('invalid')
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: "NameError: name 'contSearch' is not defined" is the error

Comment: provide more lines of the error. which file is the error for, and which file is the contSearch function in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the definition of `contSearch()` to be above the code that calls it.